# How to Get Youtube IDS from url's list PHP

Tags: youtube

Sorry may be very beginner question. i have a text area with post method where i'll list youtube URLS like this:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bT7kCbgEAqw
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AwyucYgVKb0
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QP8PyUhx1AU
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AvTg20fYZcE
```

i want just video ids, what is good way to get video ids like this:

```
bT7kCbgEAqw
QP8PyUhx1AU
AwyucYgVKb0
AvTg20fYZcE
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$vid_id = explode("?v=", $link);
$vid_id = $video_id[1];
```

Make $link your URL and then this will return everything after the ?v= in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Because youtube urls can also be http://www.youtube.com/v/id de explode wil not always work.
Following code will get the v id with both urls.

```
<?php $youtube_url =  'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXX';
parse_str(parse_url($youtube_url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $youtube); ?>

<object width="400" height="224">
<param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/<?= $youtube['v'] ?>"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/<?= $youtube['v'] ?>" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="400" height="224" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
</object>
```